# I am new to javascript frameworks, what framework should i use first

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, vue.js

I am new to javascript frameworks, what framework should i use first.
1 - AngularJS
2 - React
3 - Vue
I am working on code javascript from last 6 months.

Comment: You should read some reviews about them. AngularJS and React are used for big apps, whereas Vue is too simple (and therefore easier to use, but not manage). React is harder to set up, but lighter and _possibly faster_ than AngularJS. (Switching to Angular 2/4/5 would require learning TypeScript)

Comment: Honestly, I'd recommend learning [Knockout](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/) because it is the simplest technology and has a great tutorial (linked).

Comment: I would suggest you to go with React or Vue because for angular it is must that you have knowledge of typescript and react is more modern then AngularJS so, I would suggest you to go with Reactjs for now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can start with any framework,
Here is little bit difference between all these frameworks.

1. Angular is framework by Google.
2. React is library of Facebook.
3. Vue is framework of Evan You.

All frameworks and libraries are open source.
React has bigger community than others.